# How to give Custom Validation Messages in Package.json "configuration" property in vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to add additional configuration properties in "Settings Wizard" of my Vscode Extension. I added below code snippet in package.json to get those configuration properties in settings UI

```
"configuration": [
            {
                "title": "Sample Configuration",
                "properties": {
                    "ProjectName": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "",
                        "description": "Enter any customized name",
                        "order": 0
                    },
                    "ProjectDescriptionFile": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "",
                        "description": "A relative path starts with backward or forward slash",
                        "pattern": "^(\\\\|/)+[a-zA-z0-9\\s_@\\-^!#$%&+={}[\\]/]+\\.dsc",
                        "order": 1
                    },
                    "ProjectInformationFile": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "",
                        "description": "A relative path starts with backward or forward slash",
                        "pattern": "^(\\\\|/)+[a-zA-z0-9\\s_@\\-^!#$%&+={}[\\]/]+\\.(ini|cfg)",
                        "order": 2
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```

**Issue**

I am not able to add custom validation messages in settings UI by any property found. Vscode is simply showing the regex as validation message is not useful to users

[image: Settings UI in Sample Extension]

**Github Repository Link**

https://github.com/vijitha311/Sample_Vscode_Extension

Do any property like "message" or something available to make custom validation messages in Configuration?

Comment: the screen shot is correct, the empty string does not match the regex, supply a valid default property, not the empty string, or add the empty string in the regex `^$|otherstuff`

Comment: @rioV8 Let me add empty string also however while typing a value which doesn't satisfy the regex vscode will show validation message as "Value must match regex 'pattern'". This validation message is not clearly understandable from layman perspective. Is there any property available to give custom validation messages like "Enter the file path ends with .dsc"

Comment: The description is a good place to mention this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know when it was added but there is this option:

```
patternErrorMessage
```

which I tested and it works like this:

```
"myID.mySetting": {   // some setting
   "type": "object",
    "order": 3,
    "additionalProperties": {
       "type": "string",
       "pattern": "#\\d{4}",    // some pattern
       "patternErrorMessage": "bad hex value"
    }
}
```

Although it is documented at [configuration property schema](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#Configuration-property-schema) there is no intellisense for it in the editor.  I have filed an issue on it: [No intellisense for 'patternErrorMessage' in package.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/186126).